# Expand the copy and paste the function

Tags: android

Is it possible to expand the Android copy and paste functionality?

I want to expand it with a new button and a function call from my application.

[image]

Comment: No, there's no hooks for that.  An application can do it, but it won't work from other apps.

Comment: Do u mean expand/collapse functionality with a button click ?

Comment: expand/collapse the functionality of the text marker function from android with a button

Comment: You can use the Share functionality for that.

Comment: Gerald, have you a tutorial/demo for that? Write a answer.

Comment: There is a sample [in the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/samples/ActionBarCompat-ShareActionProvider/index.html).

Comment: use clipboard framework http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html